# DRAM Self-Refresh not the Lowest Power Mode

Tags: power, current-measurement, computer-architecture, dram, ddr3

I have a `DDR3L Samsung DRAM` on my Laptop. Based on page 23 of its [datasheet](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/resource/2017/11/DS_4GB_1.35V_DDR3_4Gb_E_die_UnbufferedSODIMM_Rev11.pdf), `IDD6` or the `Self-Refresh` current is much higher than `IDD2P0`, `IDD2P1` and `IDD3P`, which are the `Precharge/Active Power-Down` modes. Of course, `IDD5B` (i.e., the `Burst Refresh` current, which is responsible for refresh when `Self-Refresh` is not used) should be *scaled* based on the refresh period and *added* to the latter three values. But, even after that, it seems that the `Self-Refresh` power mode, is not the deepest power mode in this `DRAM` device. Am I missing something?

---

**UPDATE:**

This is a simplified state diagram of a `Micron 1Gb DDR3` SDRAM device.
[image]
There exists a `Refreshing` and a `Self-Refresh` state. Periodic refreshes during normal device operation are done in the former state. `Self-Refresh` is a low power mode (similar to `Precharge Power-Down`, etc) in which no I/O is possible and any exit from this mode requires a relatively long *resynchronization delay*.

Here is a figure from [IAMEM: Interaction-Aware Memory Energy Management](https://www.usenix.org/conference/atc13/technical-sessions/presentation/bi):
[image: Power Consumption of a DRAM Rank with 8 Micron 1Gbit DDR3-1066 devices]
As can be seen, `Self-Refresh` is the *deepest power mode* and has a small power consumption of `22mW`. But in the `Samsung DRAM` that I mentioned at the beginning of the post, `Self-Refresh` does **not** seem to be the *deepest power mode* (based on the `current` values in the referenced datasheet). This seems *counter-intuitive*.

Comment: Refreshing DRAM takes power. That's just a fact of life, and why low power systems use SRAM. If that's not what you're missing, clarify the question.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I updated the question.

Comment: OK have you designed a power down mode including Burst Refresh over the whole memory' meeting all the timings necessary to support that? Did it come out at less than 22mW overall?

Comment: The *periodic refresh* power consumption value is included in every state other than `SELF_REF`, in the above figure. The value for `Self-Refresh` power consumption, in the above figure, is OK. But it seems not to be the case for my `Samsung` DRAM. Its `IDD6` is **too** large and **adding** the periodic refresh power consumption (which should be *scaled* according to the refresh interval) will **not** lead to a large enough power consumption for the **other** low power states.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to attempt to understand from that datasheet; it's not detailed enough, it's just a summary to cover the module. There will be much better information in the datasheet for the device it uses, whose part number is given in that datasheet.

Comment: There are some power simulation tools such as `Micron Power-Calc`, `DRAMPower` and `Vampire` that use the currents as the input. The model used for `DDR3` for `Micron Power-Calc` can be found, here: https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn41_01ddr3_power.pdf. The power consumption for *each power mode* and the *total power consumption* are shown in, equations `26` and `27`, respectively. The `Self-Refresh` energy is not shown, there. But `DRAMPower` uses a similar method by using its current (i.e., `IDD6`) as input.